# Does coredata save after a change like this?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data

I have CoreData in my app, with an Entry class, which contains an NSOrderedSet of Media classes.

I then have this code, for adding a new Media item to the NSOrderedSet:

```
-(void)addImage:(UIImage *)image isInPhotoLibrary:(BOOL)isInPhotoLibrary {

    Media *media = [[Media alloc] init];
    media.type = @"Image";
    media.originalImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    media.isInPhotoLibrary = [NSNumber numberWithBool:isInPhotoLibrary];

    [self addMediaObject:media];

}
```

Will this automatically save the changes, or will I have to do it myself. If so, will i then need to pass in a context to do this, or is there another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it won't.. If you want to save changes to Database in Core data you gotta call save function for that.. I assume `Media` is kind of `NSManagedObject` class. To save the changes to `persistent store` you have to call `save` method . Until then the changes are just temporary present on your `scratch board/ ManagedObjectContext`.

This is how I save changes:

```
Worker *worker =  (Worker *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Worker" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

worker.name=txtContact.text;
worker.address=txtAddress.text;
worker.zipCode=txtZip.text;
worker.city=txtCity.text;
worker.mobile=txtMobile.text;

 NSError *error;

if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
{
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, this code doesn't have any Core Data references at all.

Is Media an NSManagedObject? If so you need to be creating it like so:

```
Media *media = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Media" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

This will put it in your managed object context.

If you then want to persist it, you will need to call save: on the managed object context.

EDIT ALSO....

In your Entry class, you will probably have a generated method that you use to add objects to the NSSet. It will be in a category (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors) on the Entry header file

```
- (void)addMediaObject:(Media *)value;
```

Comment: And typically you need to do the reverse pointer (unless there isn't an inverse relationship).